# Why some questions appear with a blue/cyan title?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-interface

The main page of the site now appears to me as depicted below:

[image: Main page of the site, with some questions in blue]

The first and third question there have a blue/cyan title: I supposed that it denotes that a question has been recently modified, but that's not the case, indeed the second question in the list as been modified too but it has the classical color (darker than the normal one since I visualized it).

What does this coloring mean?

Comment: See this main meta: [Watched question titles are changed to blue on themed sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381863/watched-question-titles-are-changed-to-blue-on-themed-sites)

Comment: @linksassin Thanks! I had that suspect, but I was confused since some questions do not present the blue title, when I click on the list of my watched tags..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was indeed a bug, and theme colors have been restored. Staff Dan Cormier [reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381914/674198):

> This issue was caused by a non-theme color being set on watched post summary titles in a recent design system change. We've reverted that change and shipped the reversion. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 0):

The blue title indicates a question has [a tag that you are watching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381863/watched-question-titles-are-changed-to-blue-on-themed-sites). The reason for the change, along with the [darkening of the "answer" green](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381858/why-has-the-green-accepted-answer-indicator-become-darker-on-all-the-sites), is for [increased visual accessibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so).